# Can't import installed Python modules

Tags: module, pip

Whenever I download a Python module, I can't run it. What am I doing wrong?

I've installed it using:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

It appears to have been installed successfully:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list
Package Version
--------------- ---------
certifi 2020.6.20
clipboard 0.0.4
colorama 0.4.3
cycler 0.10.0
handcalcs 0.8.1
kiwisolver 1.2.0
matplotlib 3.3.1
numpy 1.19.1
Pillow 7.2.0
pip 20.2.3
pyparsing 2.4.7
pyperclip 1.7.0
python-dateutil 2.8.1
qrcode 6.1
six 1.15.0
sqrc 0.0.3
```

But when running code where I try to import the module, this is what a get:

```
    import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

That can be specific for a programming platform you are using. Some platforms like PyCharm enable to install modules directly from themselves so using modules becomes much easier.